# Idhttp + Download + Delphi + ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, delphi, idhttp

I need to program an application with Delphi that goes into this site and uses the form to get an .exe file (in fact, the site sends a .ex_ file that you have to manually rename).

http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo

Via browser I just click on the checkbox on the left of "Cenários de Margem - CORE" then click on the Download button and get the file automatically.

I managed to work with .dat files from other site, now I don't know what might be wrong.

I think the problem should be with the content type or how i'm saving the file.

This is what I got so far:

```
procedure DownloadViaPost;
var
  objHttp: TIdHttp;
  sUrl: String;
  sGetRequest: String;
  objParametrosPost: TStringList;
  objRespostaPost: TStringStream;
  sViewState: String;
  sEventValidation: String;
begin
  sUrl := 'http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp';
  objHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  objParametrosPost := TStringList.Create;
  objRespostaPost := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    objHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
    objHttp.AllowCookies := true;
    objParametrosPost.Add('hdnStatus=ativo');
    objParametrosPost.Add('chkArquivoDownload_ativo=36');
    objParametrosPost.Add('txtDataDownload_ativo=21/08/2014');
    objParametrosPost.Add('imgSubmeter.x=31');
    objParametrosPost.Add('imgSubmeter.y=9');
    objParametrosPost.Add('imgSubmeter=ativo');
    objHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream exe';
    objHttp.Post(sUrl, objParametrosPost, objRespostaPost);
    objRespostaPost.SaveToFile('C:\Download.ex_');
  finally
     FreeAndNil(objHttp);
     FreeAndNil(objParametrosPost);
     FreeAndNil(objRespostaPost);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like a browser would, you need to first retreive the download page to get the server's cookies, then post the download request so the cookies can be sent back to the server.

Try this:

```
procedure DownloadViaPost;
var
  objHttp: TIdHttp;
  objRespostaPost: TMemoryStream;
  objParametrosPost: TStringList;
begin
  objHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    objHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
    objHttp.AllowCookies := true;

    objHttp.Get('http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo');

    objRespostaPost := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      objParametrosPost := TStringList.Create;
      try
        objParametrosPost.Add('hdnStatus=ativo');
        objParametrosPost.Add('chkArquivoDownload_ativo=36');
        objParametrosPost.Add('txtDataDownload_ativo=22/08/2014');
        objParametrosPost.Add('imgSubmeter.x=37');
        objParametrosPost.Add('imgSubmeter.y=6');

        objHttp.Request.Referer := 'http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo';
        objHttp.HTTPOptions := objHttp.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoTreat302Like303];

        objHttp.Post('http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/download_ipn.asp', objParametrosPost, objRespostaPost);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(objParametrosPost);
      end;
      objRespostaPost.SaveToFile('C:\Download.exe');
    finally
      FreeAndNil(objRespostaPost);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(objHttp);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: the file keep coming corrupted, any idea why?

Comment: just opened the file in the notepad and it has the html source of the page in it

Comment: Try setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.Referer` in the `Post()` request. If that still does not work, try setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` to a value that mimics a real browser.  I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: now i'm getting this error: HTTP/1.0 501 Unsupported method('POST')

Comment: I added some more info to my answer.  The server is acting weird. It should not be treating `TIdHTTP` the way it is.

Comment: thanks for all your trouble, i'll try to figure out another way

Comment: My bad, I was having `TIdHTTP.Post()` post to the wrong URL!  I have updated my answer with code that works now.  It downloads the EXE as expected.